# Hibernate not deleting records in child table

Tags: hibernate

members.hbm.xml  has mapping is as follows:

```
<set  name="licenses">
    <key column="member_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.model.License"/>
</set>
<set  name="sessions">
    <key column="member_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.model.Session"/>
</set>
```

session.hbm.xml has:

```
<many-to-one class="com.model.Member" name="member">
  <column name="member_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

license.hbm.xml has:

```
<many-to-one name="member" column="member_id" 
                 class="com.model.Member"/>
```

Trying to perform delete in members table :

```
session.delete(member);
```

It throws an exception.

> Hibernate: update licenses set member_id=null where member_id=? 
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Column
>   'member_id' cannot be null

I tried to use  `cascade="delete-orphan"` as well. But it doesn't work.

Ideally I would like to have records in licenses and sessions table deleted as well when a particular record from member table is deleted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: tried cascade delete? (not delete-orphan)

Comment: Tried just now. Same exception.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how your entities looks like (sorry I am more used to annotation-based mapping). You have `Member  1<-->* License` right?  When we have bi-directional relationship, we usually have the "one" side using "mappedBy" (something like `inverse=true` for hbm.xml), and setup cascade on the `one` side too.  This is something I cannot see from your code, and your exception suggests to me that cascading is not working in your case.

Comment: We usually see such kind of FK update (during insert/delete) if we have a bi-directional one-to-many relationship and the "one" side is owning the relationship (which seems to be in your case).  In most cases it is not the preferable mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not familiar with hbm.xml. I shall try to explain the problem with annotation-based mapping terminology, and hopefully make up some xml example.

To simplify your problem, what you are trying to do is a bi-directional one-to-many relationship (in your case, it is actually a parent-child style relationship given you want cascade delete) :

```
        1    *
Member  <----> License
```

In Hibernate, you need to decide who is owning the relationship.  If you have the parent side (`Member`) owning the relationship, you will find insertion/deletion of `Member + License` will involve update of `member_id` in `license` table (which is what I observed from your exception).  In most case it is not preferable.  We usually let the children own the relationship.  This is done by using `mappedBy`

(pseudo-code)

```
class Member {
  //...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", cascade=ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  List<License> licenses;
}

class License {
  //...

  @ManyToOne
  Member member;
}
```

The trick here is `mappedBy`

Equivalence in hbm.xml is `inverse`:

```
// member.hbm.xml
<set  name="licenses" inverse="true" />
// of course you need to set cascade delete and delete-orphan

// license.hbm.xml
<many-to-one name="member" column="member_id" 
                 class="com.model.Member"/>
```